# LeaseExpiredException on Dynamic partitioning in Spark

Tags: hadoop, pyspark

I am working on a spark job where I am trying to read from a non-partitioned table and create a partitioned table. What I am doing is as simple as:

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/path/to/file')
df.write.partitionBy('partition_col').parquet('/new/path/to/file')
```

I am getting following error:

Folks I am working on a spark job where I am trying to read from a non-partitioned table and create a partitioned table. what i am doing is as simple as -

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('/path/to/file')
df.write.partitionBy('partition_col').parquet('/new/path/to/file')
```

I am getting following error -

```
ERROR datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201710160717_0003_m_000111
_0 aborted.
ERROR [Executor task launch worker-0] executor.Executor: Exception in task 111.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 1578)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
```

**Followed by following error lines,**

```
ERROR [Executor task launch worker-0] executor.Executor: Exception in task 111.1 in stage 3.0 (TID 1892)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /path/to/file/part/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201710160719_0003_m_000111_1/pool_id=891566/part-r-00111-40dd2140-0666-4890-aad9-12fc8ffd6777.gz.parquet (inode 160527519): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1835537666_63 does not have any open files.
```

Has anyone faced similar problem with spark or knows about any fix for the problem. I looked on google/spark issue jira i am not able to figureout the solution from there

Comment: Where is the error? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46772695/edit) the question and include the error text.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue while extending AvroOutputFormat and using saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(...). Were you able to resolve the issue? Thanks

Comment: Are you reading and writing at the same location?

Answer (score 0):

The Error occurs(in my observations) when the underlying file has changed and you are still trying to access the file or if the timeout occur.

I tried playing with time out options a few times and then tweaked my process to read and write to different location. solved issue for me.